# Pass function referencing other function to child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, the main component defines a function that has a reference to a local function like so:

```
class Root extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

    tokenizer({email, password}) {
        return this.props.client.query({
            query: getToken,
            variables: {email: email, password: password}
        }).then(response => {
            return response.data
        }).catch(error => {
            console.warn(error);
            return {}
        });
    }

    async fetchToken({email, password}) {
        const data = await this.tokenizer({email, password});
        this.props.updateToken({token: data.login});//redux dispatch to props
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.token) {
            return (
                <Home />
            )
        } else {
            return <Login fetchToken={this.fetchToken} />;
        }
    }
}
```

The child component (namely `Login`) will use `fetchToken` function like so:

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.fetchToken(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                   // ... Form HTML here
            </Form>
        )
    }
}
```

Now once form is submitted, `fetchToken` is unable to reference `this.tokenizer`, as per the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.tokenizer is not a function`

I could pass `tokenizer` method, but it in turn references other props. Thus I'd have to pass any function/state/props related, which feels like an overkill. Instead would it be possible to only call `fetchToken` by referencing it in the parent?

Comment: Can you bind tokenizer, fetchToken functions?
`tokenizer = ({email, password}) => {` and `await fetchToken = () =>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind all your methods if you want to use them in the same context.
The simpliest way to do it is to use arrow function in your class for every methods.

```
class Root extends React.Component {

    tokenizer = async ({email, password}) => {
        return this.props.client.query({
            query: getToken,
            variables: {email: email, password: password}
        }).then(response => {
            return response.data
        }).catch(error => {
            console.warn(error);
            return {}
        });
    }

    fetchToken = async ({email, password}) => {
        const data = await this.tokenizer({email, password});
        this.props.updateToken({token: data.login});//redux dispatch to props
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.token) {
            return (
                <Home />
            )
        } else {
            return <Login fetchToken={this.fetchToken} />;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed this. I did bind the function through the constructor as such `this.fetchToken = this.fetchToken.bind(this);`

Answer (score 1):

`fetchToken` has no reference to `this` so you have to either bind it or use an arrow function. To bind it you have to bind it to `this` like you do with `handleChange` and `handleSubmit` in the constructor of your login component.

As an arrow function your `fetchToken` would look like this:

```
async fetchToken = ({email, password}) => {
    const data = await this.tokenizer({email, password});
    this.props.updateToken({token: data.login});//redux dispatch to props
}
```

I suggest doing the same with tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, there is an type error when you execute this line of code:

```
const data = await this.tokenizer({email, password});
```

you are calling the `tokenizer` function with `this`, but in reality the `this` is not now pointing to the same object. if you `console.log(this.tokenizer)` it will give you `undefined`. Yeah! you catch the problem the problem is about scope. let me explain you a little bit about the scope of `this`:

When it is inside of an object’s method the function’s owner is the object. Thus the `this` keyword is bound to the object.

Yet when it is inside of a function, either stand alone function or within another function, `this` will always refer to the global scope.

This is known as a **JavaScript quirk**, meaning something that just happens within JavaScript that isn’t exactly straightforward and it doesn’t work the way you would think. This was also regarded by developers as a poor design choice, which they are now remedying with ES6's arrow functions.

You can either bind your method which developer were use to do before ES6, or now you can simply use arrow function. like so

```
async fetchToken = ({email, password}) => {
    const data = await this.tokenizer({email, password});
    this.props.updateToken({token: data.login});//redux dispatch to props
}
```

Similarly, you can make tokenizer function also as arrow function.